# How do I wrap this code into a python module?

Tags: python

I am following [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) python tutorial. I defined the User class in a module so that I don't have to retype it if I re-do the tutorial (which always seems to happen in tutorials).

Here is my user.py file that defines the module:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', password='%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
```

In the python interpreter I write the following:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
>>> Base = declarative_base()
>>> from user import user //NameError: name 'Base' is not defined
```

Where should I define Base so that the User module sees it? How would a real pythonista go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.py` needs to `import` everything it depends on, or it won't know about it (even if other modules do). So:

> user.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', password='%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
```

The `NameError` you're getting is when `user` tries to declare the class `User` subclassed from `Base`